# Path Inclusion/Global variable not working?

Tags: php, oop, include, require

Simply put, my config file includes my database class, and the config file has in it:

```
global $db;
$db = new database(DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

That file is root/config.php

Moving on to root/functions/func.newpage.php doesn't have any includes/requires, and uses $db->classfunction since the file I'm working with:

root/newpage.php - requires the config file, as well as func.newpage.php.

However I still come up with: Undefined variable db.

Anything you guys are seeing I'm not? Thanks! Let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this `global $db` inside of a function? If not, remove that line, because `global` is used to add an existing global variable to the scope of a function.

Anyway, if you want to make sure that you're including the config file, you could add an `echo("config")` at the top of the config script, and you'll be sure that it was included right.

Good luck!

Comment: In that case, I took out the global. I did the echo trick and it is indeed getting the config file. I even threw in a conditional in the func file that said if (!$db), then to set it, and I'm still returning the same error.

Comment: when you look for $db in newpage.php, you're out of any function too, right? try to put a var_dump($db) just after the include, and see what happens.

Comment: I'm always out of function, however when I use $db in the func file I'm in a function. ---- All is fixed by placing global $db; within the function in the func file. -- However, not sure if it's the best way.

Comment: it is a way :-) maybe you have to check if this function that is modifying $db, will be called from more than one place, and if it happens, something could fail. It's up to you, but no, there's nothing specially wrong to use global inside a function if it is your design, and you respect it and document it all over the site. Good luck with this!